# Not able to set weight to linear layout in android

Tags: android

I am making edit box to appear 70% and calender about 20% with space in middle for datepicker.But it is not algining properly and half image is being cut.How could i correct this.

```
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/Datelayout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="100">
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="-Select Date-"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/customborder" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="40"
            android:onClick="addGroup"
            android:background="@drawable/Calender" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not specify **width** in case of **weights**. Set width of button as well as edittext to **0dp** instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Datelayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:weightSum="100" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_weight="70"
    android:hint="-Select Date-"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="15dip" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Button2"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_weight="30"
    android:background="@drawable/Calender"
    android:onClick="addGroup" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/Datelayout"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:weightSum="100">
        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="-Select Date-"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/customborder" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:onClick="addGroup"
            android:background="@drawable/Calender" />
      </LinearLayout>
```

**It's Done.**

Answer (score 0):

you can do code as following

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/Datelayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:weightSum="100">
    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="-Select Date-"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_weight="15"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:onClick="addGroup"
        android:background="@drawable/Calender" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/Datelayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:gravity="center_horizontal"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   >
    <EditText
        android:layout_weight="7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="-Select Date-"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:onClick="addGroup"
        android:background="@drawable/Calender" />
  </LinearLayout>
```